# Why does inserting a ferrite core into a loop antenna increase its radiation resistance?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electrical-resistance, antennas

I have been reading the Loop Antenna section of *Antenna Theory* by Constantine Balanis and trying to understand how exactly a ferrite core improves the performance of a small loop antenna. Balanis writes,

> The radiation resistance, and in turn the antenna efficiency, can be raised by increasing the circumference of the loop. Another way to increase the radiation resistance, without increasing the electrical dimensions of the antenna, would be to insert within
> its circumference a ferrite core that has a tendency to increase the magnetic flux, the magnetic field, the open-circuit voltage, and in turn the radiation resistance of the loop.

**How exactly does increasing the magnetic flux (adding the ferrite core) increase the antenna's radiation resistance?** Balanis claims the voltage increases, and presumably deduces that the radiation resistance increases likewise from the equation *V=IR*. However, this would only follow if we knew that the current *I* did not increase as the flux increased, which is not obvious to me. It also is not obvious to me why the voltage increases in the first place!

Answer (score 2):

A loop radiator is a magnetic dipole that is controlled by its current. To make its radiation resistance larger one could make the loop longer whose perimeter to be on the order of a wavelength, or so. Another way would be is by having it more windings, each winding itself is a dipole and they are parallel with each other if tightly wound. If in addition we can fill the coil with a high permeability material, a ferrite, its inductance, thus its dipole moment, also increases along with the radiation resistance. It is still current driven but the induced voltage between the driving points increases.

Comment: Why does increasing the coil's inductance/dipole moment increase its radiation resistance?

Comment: ultimately it  has to do with the amount that a current element is radiating, see Eqs. 3-53 or 5-2 in Balanis. The vector potential of a current is proportional to the permeability of the medium and the length of  the current. In 5-18, and 5-19 you see  that the radiated field components of a small circular loop are proportional to $\pi a^2 I_0$ that is the loop's the magnetic dipole moment.